# Running element wise conditional statements in a function

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I’m new to Python and I made a standard atmospheric conditions function that tells me the pressure, density, and temperature, at a certain height. I would like to run a range of heights and plot each atmospheric property as the height changes. My issue is the function has conditional statements because the equations change at a certain height so I get the error “The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()”.

```
#Atmo calculations 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Standard_Atmo(h):
  #constants english units
  Psl   = 2116.2   #lb/ft^2
  ROHsl = 0.0023769 #slug/ft^3
  Tsl   = 518.69   #R
  a     = -0.00356 #R/ft
  g     = 32.2     #ft/s^2
  R     = 1718     #ft-lb/slug R
  if h <= 36150:
    T = Tsl + np.multiply(a,h)
    P = Psl*np.power((T/Tsl),(-g/(a*R)))
    roh = ROHsl*np.power((T/Tsl),((-g/(a*R))-1))
    return P, roh, T
  else:
    T = 389.996 
    Pconst = Psl*np.power((T/Tsl),(-g/(a*R)))
    rohconst = ROHsl*np.power((T/Tsl),((-g/(a*R))-1))
    P = Pconst*np.exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-36150))
    roh = rohconst*np.exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-36150))
    return P, roh, T

h = np.arange(0,60000, 500)
T = Standard_Atmo(h)[2]
plt.plot(T,h)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there a way to run an array through a function with conditional statements or an alternate method? Apologies for how the code may look.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are very different from each other, so in general, no. You need to calculate the h's for the first condition and the h's for the second condition. This can be done all in the function though:

```
def Standard_Atmo(heights):
  #constants english units
  Psl   = 2116.2   #lb/ft^2
  ROHsl = 0.0023769 #slug/ft^3
  Tsl   = 518.69   #R
  a     = -0.00356 #R/ft
  g     = 32.2     #ft/s^2
  R     = 1718     #ft-lb/slug R
  h_below, h_above = heights[heights<=36150], heights[heights>36150]
  answers = []
  for h in h_below: 
    T = Tsl + np.multiply(a,h)
    P = Psl*np.power((T/Tsl),(-g/(a*R)))
    roh = ROHsl*np.power((T/Tsl),((-g/(a*R))-1))
    answers.append([P, roh, T])
  for h in h_above:
    T = 389.996 
    Pconst = Psl*np.power((T/Tsl),(-g/(a*R)))
    rohconst = ROHsl*np.power((T/Tsl),((-g/(a*R))-1))
    P = Pconst*np.exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-36150))
    roh = rohconst*np.exp((-g/(R*T))*(h-36150))
    answers.append([P, roh, T])
  return answers
```

Of course this function could be cleaned up quite a bit. `answers` could be pre-allocated instead of using a python list, and the for loops could be eliminated if you want to calculate over the whole array at once. Etc.

Comment: How would I go about plotting T vs height? I don't have too much experience with manipulating the different data structures in Python.